Error: expected expression
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<pair<int, int> > data;
    int a, b;
    freopen("test.txt", "r", stdin);
    while(cin >> a >> b) {
        data.push_back({a, b});
    }
    cout << data.size() << endl;
}

Вообщем на макбуке решил установить VSCode для c++, компилятор clang. Проблема возникает в строке "data.push_back({a, b})" и пишет, что в данном месте ошибка expected expression. Не знаю как исправить данную ошибку.

Возможно используется старый (до С++11) стандарт, переключитесь на более новый, например на С++20.

clang не поддерживает инициализацию списка векторов в таком виде.
Попробуйте так
data.push_back(make_pair(a, b));


Clang это конечно поддерживает. Скорее автору не хватило флажка -std=c++11 (или новее). Яблочный кланг по умолчанию собирает с -std=c++98.
